# Imageviews in my gridlayout are overflowing the maximum width - android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm learning java for android and making a connect 3 games using a grid layout and image views according to the tutorial. I have made my gridlayout a square and made the width match the width of the main view. The gridlayout as three columns and three rows.

I add into the image views that will be the counters, I've added three in the code below but as you can see the width does not match the cells and goes over the width of the gridlayout. I don't want to hardcore the dp values as I want it to fit for all screens.

Can someone advise what to do?

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="272dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:rowCount="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />



</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

Looks like this (wrong):
[Grid of counters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eQ0z.png)

Comment: You can change `layout_width` and `layout_height` to a smaller one and it should help you resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add weights and set it to 1 . And set all width and height to 0dp .

```
<ImageView
       //And you remaining code   
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_columnWeight="1"
       android:layout_rowWeight="1"
       />
```